# Jenkins cannot find geckodriver from PATH

Tags: linux, jenkins, path, robotframework, geckodriver

My server is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9. and Jenkins is 2.2773.

I have set my home folder to be in PATH (/usr/RES/username) and that folder contains geckodriver and chromedriver. If I go to some other folder and type geckodriver or chromedriver I can launch it, so that means those are in PATH, am I correct? If I type `echo $PATH` I can see the folder.

But still when I try to run a job (Robot Framework testcase) in Jenkins I keep getting:

> WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

or

> WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

If I run API tests that doesn't require a browser, those Robot Framework tests perform fine, so there shouldn't be any issue with Robot Framework or Python.

Python2 is 2.7.5 and Python3 is 3.6.8

How can I fix this?

Comment: The jenkins process may use a different PATH than you get when you run interactively. You need to figure out what the PATH is for the jenkins process.

Comment: Thanks Bryan Oakley. That sounds like a plan. How can I found what the PATH is for the jenkins process?

Comment: You can create a temporary jenkins job that prints it out. Or maybe just read the documentation.